# selenium webdriver: form data not present after submit

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a page in which I log in and then fill in some forms. After submitting the first form, a new page appears with new forms. Some data is taken from the forms before (as it should be), but some data is missing.

If I do exactly the same I do with webdriver by hand, everything works fine and all the data from form 1 is present in form 2.

The Code is pretty simple:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.example.com")

### login ###
driver.find_element_by_id("UserName").send_keys("foo")
driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("bar")
driver.find_element_by_id("LoginButton").click()

# fill first form and submit
driver.find_element_by_id("Info").send_keys("data")
driver.find_element_by_id("info2").send_keys("data2")
driver.find_element_by_id("Submit").click()

# new page where "data" should be present but isn't
# ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

I thought I may have to use cookies? If so, how do I use them? Just found C# examples and don't know where to import the Cookie class from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visit the cookie section of this tutorial
http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/navigating.html

Comment: Nice link, didn't know about that one!

Comment: Please do not post just a link. Especially that it's no longer available.